# Unable to start windows service

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I have an asynchronous socket listener class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.Repository;
using log4net.Appender;


namespace GatewayWindowsService.Code
{


    // State object for reading client data asynchronously
    public class ListenerStateObject
    {
        // Client  socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public class AsynchronousSocketListener
    {
        // The address for the remote device
        private const string address = "172.25.17.119";

        // The port number for the remote device.
        private const int port = 11000;

        //LOG4NET LOG
        private ILog log;

        // Thread signal.
        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public AsynchronousSocketListener(ILog log)
        {
            this.log = log;
        }

        public void StartListening()
        {

            // Data buffer for incoming data.
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
            // The DNS name of the computer
            // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(address);
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(100);

                //while (true)
                //{
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.

                log.Info("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
                //}

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(e.ToString());
            }

        }

        public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Signal the main thread to continue.
            allDone.Set();

            // Get the socket that handles the client request.
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            // Create the state object.
            ListenerStateObject state = new ListenerStateObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, ListenerStateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }

        public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            String content = String.Empty;

            // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            ListenerStateObject state = (ListenerStateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the client socket. 
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
                // more data.
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                {
                    // All the data has been read from the 
                    // client. Display it on the console.

                    log.Info("Read " + content.Length + " bytes from socket. \n Data : " + content);
                    // Echo the data back to the client.
                    Send(handler, content);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Not all data received. Get more.
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, ListenerStateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Send(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                log.Info("Sent " + bytesSent + " bytes to client.");

                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(e.ToString());
            }
        }

}
```

}

Now I use this class on a windows service and instantiate it like this:

```
//EXECUTED WHEN THE WINDOWS SERVICE IS STARTED
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            log.Info("Windos Service Initiated");                       

            sListener = new AsynchronousSocketListener(log);
            sListener.StartListening();
        }
```

When I try and start this services from the services, the progression bar goes and goes and in the end I get this error:

> Windows could not start the Gateway
>   Windows Service on Local Computer
>   Error 1053: The service did not
>   respond to the start or control
>   request in a timely fashion

How do I solve this, starting the windows service with the socket listening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not right way to block the OnStart() function of windows service. You only do the initialization in this function and return. So the proper way is that you should launch a new thread from OnStart() function and return. You should listen for the incoming connections in that newly created thread.

Here is your modified function to run a separate thread.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    log.Info("Windos Service Initiated");

    sListener = new AsynchronousSocketListener(log);

    // Create a new thread. Its better if you declare myThread as class variable.
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sListener.StartListening));
    myThread.Start(); 
}
```

Please ignore if there is some syntax or spelling error in the code. I'm currently using Mac and do not have Visual Studio :)

Comment: I have edited my post and added example code... please see above. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your listener waits for a connection within `StartListening()`. The services.msc-Panel waits for `OnStart()` to complete and this does not during a timeout period. You should start listening asynchronously or push the listing code to another thread.